# CXF java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to com.tibco.ur.schemas.getocr.Output

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, cxf

I have a WSDL that defines an "anyType" element :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created by TIBCO WSDL-->
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GenericWS" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GenericWS">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gws="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GenericWS" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GenericWS" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

            <xs:import namespace="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GetBranch" schemaLocation="GetBranch.xsd" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GetOCR" schemaLocation="GetOCR.xsd" />

            ...
            <xs:complexType name="ResultList">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Result" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Status">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="Return" type="xs:int"/>
                                            <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element ref="gws:Input" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element ref="gws:Output" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:attribute name="QiD" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="Service" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="TiD" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="Input" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="Output" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="Queries" type="gws:QueryList"/>
            <xs:element name="Results" type="gws:ResultList"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:service name="GenericWS.Service">
        <wsdl:port name="PortTypeEndpoint" binding="tns:PortTypeEndpointBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8101/Generic/GenericWS.Service.serviceagent/PortTypeEndpoint"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <wsdl:portType name="PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="Operation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:Request"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:Response"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="PortTypeEndpointBinding" type="tns:PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="Operation">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="/Generic/GenericWS.Service.serviceagent/PortTypeEndpoint/Operation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Input"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Output"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:message name="Request">
        <wsdl:part name="Input" element="tns:Queries"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="Response">
        <wsdl:part name="Output" element="tns:Results"/>
    </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

It uses the GetOCR.xsd as you can see :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:spe="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GetOCR"
     targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GetOCR"
     elementFormDefault="qualified"
     attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Input">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CO_EXTREF" type="xs:string">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ValidTodayOnly" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Output">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Specific Output for GetBransh generic service.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Store" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:extension base="spe:Simple">
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="OCR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="Date" type="spe:YearMonth"/>
                                            <xs:element name="Sales" type="spe:Amount"/>
                                            <xs:element name="Cost" type="spe:Amount"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Simple">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="Label" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="YearMonth">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Year" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="Month" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Amount">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="VatType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Currency" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I generated the class files in Maven :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-cxf-Generic</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/GenericWS.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I do call the web service with CXF :

```
final GenericWSService genericWSService = new GenericWSService();
final PortType portType = genericWSService.getPortTypeEndpoint();
...
final ResultList resultList = portType.operation(queryList);
```

The returned XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:Results xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GenericWS">
            <ns0:Result Service="GetOCR" QiD="ref_89100-00281"
                Version="00">
                <ns0:Status>
                    <ns0:Return>0</ns0:Return>
                    <ns0:Message>Ok</ns0:Message>
                </ns0:Status>
                <ns0:Input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:tibco_c2s_ns0="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GetOCR"
                    xsi:type="tibco_c2s_ns0:Input">
                    <tibco_c2s_ns0:CO_EXTREF>89100-00281</tibco_c2s_ns0:CO_EXTREF>
                    <tibco_c2s_ns0:ValidTodayOnly>false</tibco_c2s_ns0:ValidTodayOnly>
                </ns0:Input>
                <ns0:Output>
                    <ns1:Store xmlns:ns1="http://www.tibco.com/UR/schemas/GetOCR">
                        <ns1:ID>4814</ns1:ID>
                        <ns1:Label>FOOT LOCKER</ns1:Label>
                        <ns1:OCR>
                            <ns1:Date>
                                <ns1:Year>2014</ns1:Year>
                                <ns1:Month>3</ns1:Month>
                            </ns1:Date>
                            <ns1:Sales>
                                <ns1:VatType>NET</ns1:VatType>
                                <ns1:Currency>EUR</ns1:Currency>
                                <ns1:Amount>1728832.0</ns1:Amount>
                            </ns1:Sales>
```

I can go throught this response until i enter into the xsd part :

```
final List<ResultList.Result> results = resultList.getResult();

            for (final ResultList.Result result : results) {

                final ResultList.Result.Status status = result.getStatus();
                final int codeRetour = status.getReturn();
                final String message = status.getMessage();

                final List<Object> outputs = result.getOutput();

                for (final Object output : outputs) {

                    final Output outputOCR = (Output) output;

                    final List<Output.Store> stores = outputOCR.getStore();
```

The last line throws an "java.lang.ClassCastException" (of course) :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to com.tibco.ur.schemas.getocr.Output
```

I've tried many things (with ElementNSImpl) but nothing works :-(

Any idea would be welcome...

Th.

Answer (score 2):

According to the wsdl/top level schema, the "Output" element is an xsd:anyType.  Thus, JAXB will unmarshall that to a DOM Element unless there is information on the wire to say what type it is.  That would basically mean an xsi:type="tns:Output" attribute would be required.

If you KNOW it's going to be an Output, change the schema in the wsdl to make the Output element be of type Output.  (and I'd do the same for the Input)